# Is there a name for this type of convergence?

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, terminology

I'm reading one of T. Ando's "Structure of operators with numerical radius one" where he constructs a sequence $X_n\in B(H)$ satisfying $\langle X_nh,h\rangle=\displaystyle\inf_g\left\langle \begin{pmatrix} I& T^*/2\\ T/2& X_{n-1}\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}h\\ g\end{pmatrix},\begin{pmatrix} h\\ g\end{pmatrix}\right\rangle$ for a given $T$ with $w(T)\leq 1$.

He then says $X_n$ converges decreasingly to some $X$.

This got me thinking whether this is what he meant or not: $X_n\to X$ if $\langle X_nh,h\rangle\to\langle Xh,h\rangle$ for all $h\in H$?

Is there a name for the topology induced here? Or Ando meant something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$X_n$ converges decreasingly to $X$ means that $\langle X_n h,h\rangle\to \langle X h,h\rangle$ for all $h\in H$ **and** $(\langle X_n h,h\rangle)_n$ is a decreasing sequence for all $h\in H$. This is convergence in the weak operator topology (WOT) or equivalently strong operator topology (SOT) or a bunch of other operator topologies, which all coincide for bounded monotone nets of self-adjoint operators, but are different in general.

Comment: Thanks MaoWao. But isn't WOT convergence: for all $k\in H$, $\langle X_i h,k\rangle\to \langle X h,k\rangle$ for all $h\in H$?

Comment: @chhro That's true, but you can write $\langle X_i h,k\rangle$ as a finite linear combination of terms of the form $\langle X_i \tilde h,\tilde h\rangle$ (polarization), so that's actually equivalent (for all nets, not only monotone ones).

Comment: You're right. That's amazing actually.